# Merge duplicates and sum columns

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I need some code to find duplicates in Column B, then if found sum Columns I, J & L. Then delete the duplicate rows, only leaving the 1 instance.

I have a button click on Sheet1, and the code needs to run on Sheet4.

I currently have this code, which does the task perfectly, but it only works on the active sheet, i cannot seem to make it work for a different sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False      '### Excel wont update its screen while executing this macro. This is a huge performace boost
Dim SumCols() '### declare a second empty array for our sum columns
SumCols() = Array(9, 10, 12)         '### the second array stores the columns which should be summed up
'### the next line sets our range for searching dublicates. Starting at cell A2 and ending at the last used cell in column A
Set searchrange = Range([b1], Columns(2).Find(what:="*", after:=[b1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious))
For Each cell In searchrange            '### now we start looping through each cell of our searchrange
    Set Search = searchrange.Find(cell, after:=cell, lookat:=xlWhole)   '### searches for a dublicate. If no dub exists, it finds only itself
    Do While Search.Address <> cell.Address     '### until we find our starting cell again, these rows are all dublicates

        For i = 0 To UBound(SumCols)    '### loop through all columns for calculating the sum
            '### next line sums up the cell in our starting row and its counterpart in its dublicate row
            Cells(cell.Row, SumCols(i)) = CDbl(Cells(cell.Row, SumCols(i))) + CDbl(Cells(Search.Row, SumCols(i)))
        Next i                          '### go ahead to the next column

        Search.EntireRow.Delete         '### we are finished with this row. Delete the whole row
        Set Search = searchrange.Find(cell, after:=cell)    '### and search the next dublicate after our starting row
    Loop

Next                                    '### from here we start over with the next cell of our searchrange

                                        '### Note: This is a NEW unique value since we already deleted all old dublicates

Application.ScreenUpdating = True '### re-enable our screen updating
End Sub
```

All help is appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either select the sheet first, so it becomes the ActiveSheet:

```
Sheets("MergedData").Select
```

Or preferably reference using With (not tested):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim searchrange As Range, cell As Range, Search As Range
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim SumCols()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    SumCols() = Array(9, 10, 12)

    With Sheets("MergedData")
        Set searchrange = .Range(.Range("b1"), .Columns(2).Find(what:="*", after:=.Range("b1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious))

        For Each cell In searchrange
            Set Search = searchrange.Find(cell, after:=cell, lookat:=xlWhole)

            Do While Search.Address <> cell.Address
                For I = 0 To UBound(SumCols)
                    .Cells(cell.Row, SumCols(I)) = CDbl(.Cells(cell.Row, SumCols(I))) + CDbl(.Cells(Search.Row, SumCols(I)))
                Next I

                Search.EntireRow.Delete
                Set Search = searchrange.Find(cell, after:=cell)
            Loop
        Next
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Using `select` to specify ranges or worksheets in your code is really bad practice... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Comment: It is, which is why I said preferably reference using With Sheets("MergedData").

Comment: Hi guys, i have tried boths ways, and the only code that works is the `With Sheets("MergedData")` i get errors if i do it any other way?

Comment: So just use the one that works, using Select should be avoided where possible.

Comment: @tonester640 yeah that what i have done. Thanks again for all the help!!! Much appreciated!!!!.

Comment: @tonester640 Ah, sorry, seems I skimmed it a bit to quickly. Downvote removed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to perform the operation on every worksheet in your workbook, you just have to wrap another `for each`-loop around the rest of your code, and then specify that it is in that worksheet your range is. For the code you're posting, it'd look something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim SumCols()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  SumCols() = Array(9, 10, 12)

  For Each ws In Worksheets
    Set searchrange = Range(ws.Range("B1"), ws.Columns(2).Find(what:="*", after:=[b1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious))
    For Each cell In searchrange
      Set Search = searchrange.Find(cell, after:=cell, lookat:=xlWhole)
      Do While Search.Address <> cell.Address
        For i = 0 To UBound(SumCols)
            '### next line sums up the cell in our starting row and its counterpart in its dublicate row
            Cells(cell.Row, SumCols(i)) = CDbl(Cells(cell.Row, SumCols(i))) + CDbl(Cells(Search.Row, SumCols(i)))
        Next i
        Search.EntireRow.Delete
        Set Search = searchrange.Find(cell, after:=cell)
      Loop
    Next cell
  Next ws
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The relevant changes are the extra `for each`-loop, and changing

```
 Set searchrange = Range([b1], Columns(2).Find(what:="*", after:=[b1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious))
```

to

```
 Set searchrange = Range(ws.Range("B1"), ws.Columns(2).Find(what:="*", after:=[b1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I only need to to perform the operation on the sheet MergedData. thanks

Comment: @atame In that case you won't have to loop through all the sheets, just you just specify the worksheet prior to the range instead: `Set searchrange = Worksheets("MergedData").Range(...)`. Alternately you can refer to it by its [codename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx), to make it harder for your users to screw up anything.

Comment: I have tried that and it give me a Run-time error '9': subscript out of range?? Thanks

Comment: It seems I didn't read your code closely enough (it is quite hard to read, you may want to think about cleaning it up a little)... Anyway, you need to put the worksheet specification in front of every range-object you give an address to, but not in front of the range-function. In other words that line should look something like this: `Set searchrange = Range(Worksheet("Name").Range("B1"), Worksheets("Name").Columns(2).Find(what:="*", after:=[b1], searchdirection:=xlPrevious))` @atame

Comment: thanks for the help, but tonester640 has provide a working answer. thanks

Comment: @atame His solution is really bad practice - see the question I linked and the related answers / linked articles.